# Stuck in bootloop after flashing ROM

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, recovery-mode, custom-roms, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-star-duos

I was flashing a custom ROM on my *Samsung Galaxy Star Pro* and now it is stuck in boot loop.

- I don't have a backup of my previous ROM.
- I can not boot into recovery as one of the volume buttons is damaged yet I can boot into odin mode.
- I tried flashing stock ROM with Odin but it didn't work.
- Inspite of all that, the phone charges when I connect charger when and it is off.

Can someone help me fixing it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten yourself in a pretty bad state. Always, **always**, **ALWAYS** do a full backup if you plan to change anything at the phones system!

Which ROM have you tried to flash? Re-check, if it is specifically for your device and a **stable build**. If it's not, flash the latest stable build for your device instead. If that doesn't work, you could try to flash a different ROM - but without Backup and Recovery I don't know much more you could do.